# Deploy helm chart from Azure Container Registry

Tags: kubernetes, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm, acr

I have a multistage pipeline with the following

Stage build:

1. build docker image
2. push image to ACR
3. package helm chart
4. push helm chart to ACR

Stage deployment:

1. helm upgrade

**Push helm chart to AKS:**

```
 task: HelmDeploy@0
 displayName: 'helm publish'
 inputs:
   azureSubscriptionForACR: '$(azureSubscription)'
   azureResourceGroupForACR: '$(resourceGroup)'
   azureContainerRegistry: '$(containerRegistry)'
   command: 'save'
   arguments: '--app-version $(Version)'
   chartNameForACR: 'charts/$(imageRepository):$(Version)'
   chartPathForACR: $(chartPath)
```

**Deploy helm chart to AKS:**

```
  task: HelmDeploy@0
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceConnection: '$(kubernetesServiceConnection)'
    command: 'upgrade'
    chartType: 'Name'
    chartName: '$(containerRegistry)/charts/$(imageRepository):$(Version)'
    chartVersion: '$(Version)'
    azureSubscriptionForACR: '$(azureSubscription)'
    azureResourceGroupForACR: '$(resourceGroup)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(containerRegistry)'
    install: true
    releaseName: $(Version)
```

**Error:**

```
failed to download "<ACR>/charts/<repository>:0.9.26" at version "0.9.26" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

**ACR:**
`az acr repository show-manifests --name <org> --repository helm/charts/<repository> --detail`

```
  {
    "changeableAttributes": {
      "deleteEnabled": true,
      "listEnabled": true,
      "readEnabled": true,
      "writeEnabled": true
    },
    "configMediaType": "application/vnd.cncf.helm.config.v1+json",
    "createdTime": "2021-02-02T11:54:54.1623765Z",
    "digest": "sha256:fe7924415c4e76df370630bbb0248c9296f27186742e9272eeb87b2322095c83",
    "imageSize": 3296,
    "lastUpdateTime": "2021-02-02T11:54:54.1623765Z",
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
    "tags": [
      "0.9.26"
    ]
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to `export` the helm chart from ACR before I can deploy it?

Comment: I believe you need to use azureSubscriptionEndpointForACR instead  of azureSubscriptionForACR

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @sshepel actually helped somewhat, you need to login to the registry before being able to pull. However, it is sufficient with a simple AzureCLI login.

```
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Login to Azure Container Registry
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: <Azure Resource Manager service connection to your subscription and resource group>
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az acr login --name <container registry name>.azurecr.io
```

After that it worked perfectly with the undocumented HelmDeploy task.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same issue, and only option that helped me is to add registry login step before helm upgrade.

```
- task: Bash@3
  name: registryLogin
  displayName: Login registry
  env:
   SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_APPLICATION_ID: <SPN_APP_ID>
   SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_APPLICATION_KEY: <SPN_APP_KEY>
   HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI: 1 # just in case...
  input:
   targetType: inline
   script:
     echo $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_APPLICATION_KEY | helm registry login <acr_name>.azurecr.io --username $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_APPLICATION_ID --password-stdin
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax of `helm upgrade` should be like:

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'helm upgrade'
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceConnection: connection
    command: upgrade
    chartName: '$(name)'
    chartVersion: '$(Version)'
    releaseName: azuredevopsdemo
```

Try to replace the `chartName` value to `charts/$(imageRepository)`.

Comment: How will it know that the helm chart should be taken from ACR?

Comment: There is no ACR specified in this `upgrade` command. Have you tried `chartType: filepath` and specified the file path?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. The documentation for using Helm 3 with Azure Container Regsitry in Azure Pipeline is some what lacking. So now I have a stage which package the Helm charts and adds it as pipeline artifact and the next stage downloads the artifacts and deploys that package to kubernetes.

Comment: You could add a reply and accept it as an answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @Michael could you add the answer and accept is for knowledge sharing? I am running into the same issue but when using the above solutions from others the same erorr occurs